# Boost.Asio context with TLS v. 1.2 and SSL v.3 e-mail client: ssl3 alert unexpected message

Tags: c++, ssl, boost

I have implemented e-mails interceptor in `C++` using `Boost.Asio`.
`SSL` context is `TLS v. 1.2`
`Thunderbird` connects to the program and here is an error

```
sslv3 alert unexpected message
```

As I understand TLS v.1.2 means it supports all versions below: `TLS v. 1.1, TLS v. 1.0, SSL 3.0, SSL 2.0`

This error is frequent, but mostly e-mails are sent out and are intercepted without errors.

What is the reason of the error?

Answer (score 0):

Although TLS was designed to be fully backward compatible with SSL, it's still subject to your SSL client/server implementation library (i.e. OpenSSL, GnuSSL, WinSSl, etc).  These implementations can vary by design, local security policy and are therein subject to various backward compatibility issues with SSL 3.0.  Your client is rejecting SSL 3.0 messages; therefore, if you change your SSL to more popular OpenSSL, then you should be able to bypass this issue and communicate with SSL 3.0 server.

Please check your local OS security policy to ensure that SSL 3.0 is "allowed".  In Windows, this can be checked via Internet Settings under IE optionss.